# NX - how can I build and serve node application that depends on ESM libs

Tags: nrwl-nx, nrwl

### Background

I've got an NX workspace with a react front-end and an express back-end. I want to add some dependencies to the back-end application but am having trouble adding dependencies that are ESM Libs.

When running `nx run express-server:serve` which uses the `@nx/js:node` executor I get the following error

`Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module Instead change the require of index.js in null to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.`

### Research

I have been reading any related post/thread (see list below) that I can find but I haven't been able to find a solution to this. My understanding is, that this isn't a bug with NX but with the rise of ESM only libs, there must be a workaround for this.

I did make an attempt to update my workspace to ESM but it seems the support for this in NX is lacking and the end result just produced other errors. I would like to continue using NX and be able to support the importing of ESM only libs.

**Related Threads**

- https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/11335
- https://github.com/nrwl/nx/pull/10414
- https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/10565
- https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/7872
- https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/10296
- https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/18974

**Sample code**

[nx-express-esm](https://github.com/richmondp/nx-express-esm)

- `npm i`
- `nx run express-server:build` (works)
- `nx run express-server:serve` (fails with above error)

This is a simple contrived example to demonstrate the problem. I know I could just downgrade `nanoid` to version 3 but I have other ESM libs that I can't downgrade.

Comment: This is a common problem that happens when one lib is requiring another but the type is mismatched. Sometimes it can be solved by renaming the `somefile.js` into `somefile.mjs` or `somefile.cjs`. I have no experience with NX though, so I can't say for sure.